# Reference for the claim that $X+Y$ is Gaussian whenever $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian (in the multivariate case)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb R^m$- and $\mathbb R^n$-valued random variables and $(X,Y)\sim\mathcal N((x,y),\Sigma)$ for some positive $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^{m+n}$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{(m+n)\times(m+n)}$.

> $X+Y$ is normally distributed, but what are the mean and the covariance matrix of $X+Y$?

The corresponding result for $m=n=1$ can be found at many places, but I wasn't able to find this result (for non-independent $X,Y$) in the general case.

Comment: This is a consequence of Cramér-Wolf's theorem.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Do you mean "Cramér-Wold"?

Comment: generally a probability vector $(X_1,X_2,\ldots ,X_n)$ is **defined** to be Gaussian if and only if any linear combination $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k X_k$ have a Gaussian distribution

Comment: @kimchilover: yes,  of course... My clumsy think fingers...

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, I know. From this it is easy to see that $X\sim\mathcal N_{\Sigma^{(1)}}(x,\;\cdot\;)$ and $X\sim\mathcal N_{\Sigma^{(2)}}(y,\;\cdot\;)$, where $$\Sigma^{(1)}_{ij}:=\operatorname{Cov}[X_i,X_j]\;\;\;\text{for }i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$$ and $$\Sigma^{(2)}_{ij}:=\operatorname{Cov}[Y_i,Y_j]\;\;\;\text{for }i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}.$$ But we don't immediately obtain the distribution from $X+Y$ from that.

Comment: @OliverDíaz How do you obtain this from Cramér-Wold?

Comment: $u\cdot X + v\cdot Y$ is a Gaussian for all $u,v$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Okay, but what I'm seeking for is an expression of its covariance matrix.

Comment: As mentioned, $X+ Y$ is a Gaussian vector as each linear combination of its entries is Gaussian (as a linear combination of entries of $(X,Y)$). 
Then the covariance can be computed as for any Gaussian vector $Z$ as $ \Sigma_Z = \mathbb{E}[ZZ^T] -\mathbb{E}[Z]\mathbb{E}[Z]^T$. In this case, with $ Z = X+ Y$, this will probably be a sum of the blocks of $ \Sigma 
= \Sigma_{(X,Y)}$.

Comment: There are several ways to show that $X + Y$ is Gaussian. One is by using characteristic functions. Another is by using the fact that if a vector Q is MVN, then $Q$ equals $AZ + \mu$ in distribution for some nonrandom matrix $A$, where $Z$ is a vector of i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$, and $\mu = E(Q)$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum $X + Y$ only makes sense for $m = n$, so we'll assume this is the case and take $Z = (X, Y)$.
Now, we can write
$$
X + Y
= \begin{pmatrix}I_n & I_n\end{pmatrix} Z,
$$
where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.
From this, we can conclude from standard results about the mean and covariance of a linear transformation that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(X + Y)
&= \begin{pmatrix}I_n & I_n\end{pmatrix} \mathbf{E}Z \\
&= \mathbf{E} X + \mathbf{E} Y,\\
\mathrm{Cov}(X + Y)
&= \begin{pmatrix}I_n & I_n\end{pmatrix} \mathrm{Cov}(Z)\begin{pmatrix}I_n \\I_n\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \Sigma_{11} + \Sigma_{12} + \Sigma_{12}^\mathrm{T} + \Sigma_{22},
\end{align*}
where
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Z)
= \Sigma
= \begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\
\Sigma_{12}^{\mathrm{T}} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$